# Design MapReduce job to find the maximum value below a given threshold

Tags: design-patterns, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-zookeeper

**The query:**

I am trying to design a query to find the live version of a web page at a given ***date***.

The ***date*** is passed as run-time argument. The input to a mapper is the following key -> value pair: ***webpage_id*** -> ***revision_id*** and ***revision_timestamp***.

For each ***webpage_id***, the job has to output the latest ***revision_id*** of the page that happened before the given ***date***.

**Current design:**

The mappers would discard any record with `revision_timestamp` after the threshold date and would output all other records.

The combiners would then sort all the revisions for a given webpage and output only the latest one (this is done by using an internal data structure and emitting key-value pairs at the cleanup stage of the combiners).

The reducers would do the same thing as the combiners, but on the combiner's output.

**Idea:**

I want to further optimize the job. I think it is a good idea to update a "global" variable with the latest revision processed by a mapper for a given webpage. Given that, before a mappers output a record, it would check if the revision is the "globally latest" revision for that webpage and will not emit if it isn't. If it is, he would emit the record and update the global variable. I think that this can reduce the amount of records transferred over the network and speed up the job. Do you think this idea is feasible and is it likely to improve the performance?

**Question:**

Is there a way to create and update such global variables - I read that one of the features of `ZooKeeper` is to act as a key-value store but I cannot find a code example of how to initialize or access a `ZooKeeper` record/variable inside a map task?

Are there any other ways in which I can improve the performance of my `MapReduce` job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no official way for mutable global state shared between map/reduce jobs. Surely using something like zookeeper is a possibility but most likely it is going to be a bottleneck of your flow. So it is generally not recommended.
Instead, you could track webpage_id -> max_date hash map per mapper and only emit records if a current date is later than the currently tracked max_date. Of course, this assumes that this mapping should fit in memory. If the number of page ids is too large in your use case, you may want to pre-partition the input (by webpage_id), so that each mapper will receive only a limited subset of page ids thus keeping the max date tracking map manageable in memory. Then you would just need to configure sufficient number of mappers.